# iOS 11 webview audioplayer in background

Tags: audio, wkwebview, ios11, sfsafariviewcontroller

Since update on iOS 11 my audioplayer in a webview stops when the app is in background. On iOS 10 the player keeps playing. 
Anyone else having the same problem and a fix for this?

Comment: We are also experiencing this same issue. We noticed the same issue with `AVAudioSession` but that was fixed with iOS 11.0.1 release. We will be filing a radar for this bug in regards to `SFSafariViewController` not continuing audio play while the app is backgrounded. I will post back here if we get any feedback from apple.

Comment: @JohnDeLong Could you post the issue on Open Radar please? Thanks

Comment: @WDUK Please find my Open Radar submission here: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5063448798953472

Comment: I created TSI last week and Apple confirmed that this was a bug. They asked me to submit a bug report.